# Mean of column group by multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, mean

I'm new to pandas and I am struggling with this :
I have a table like this one (of a much larger period of time) :

[image]

I want to get the mean count of a specific item, during a specific hour, of a specific day (so group by 3 specific values).
For this example, if I want the mean count of itemname1 sold Monday between 8 to 9, the output would be 4.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `df.groupby(["Item", "Day", "Hour"]).agg({"Count": "mean"})` gets you the grouped and aggregated values. Then you can query this new DataFrame for the specific combination you're interested in

Comment: @Alex Last question, my output dataframe (after the query) shows days and hours unordered. Is there any sort argument in agg or groupby to solve this ?

Comment: As [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) uses your grouping columns as an index you should call [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to set their ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the groupby function on Item, Day, and Hour:

```
# setup

import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["Monday", "8 to 9", "itemname1", "drinks", 3],
    ["Monday", "8 to 9", "itemname1", "drinks", 5],
    ["Monday", "12 to 13", "itemname2", "drinks", 1],
    ["Tuesday", "8 to 9", "itemname3", "drinks", 1],
    ["Tuesday", "8 to 9", "itemname1", "drinks", 2],
    ["Tuesday", "9 to 10", "itemname2", "drinks", 3],
    ["Tuesday", "12 to 13", "itemname1", "drinks", 2]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Day", "Hour", "Item", "Category", "Count"])
means = df.groupby(["Item", "Day", "Hour"]).agg({"Count": "mean"})
example = means.loc[("itemname1",  "Monday",   "8 to 9")].values[0]

print(example)
```

Output

```
4
```

Comment: didn't know the groupby.agg function, thanks !